# Removing whitespaces in QLineEdit

Tags: pyqt

I have been using `.strip()` to remove the leading/ trailing whitespaces, eg. if my input content is `abc` or `abc`, it works in my cause.
However is there a way that I can embedded this into the QLineEdit?

Something akin to setting a validator that uses the following for only numeric inputs?

```
int_validator = QtGui.QIntValidator()
num_input.setValidator(int_validator) # where num_input is a QLIneEdit
```

Comment: Do you want that spaces are not allowed in the QLineEdit?

Comment: How would a validator know that a space is *going to become* leading/trailing whilst the user is typing it? For example, if the user tries to enter the text "black and white", what should the validator do when the space after "black" is typed? This seems totally ambiguous and unworkable, so I don't think a validator is the right solution. A much simpler and better solution would be to subclass the `QLineEdit` and reimplement the `text` method so that it returns the right thing.

Comment: Hi all, yes I do not want my QLineEdit to allow any spaces in the inputs.